# SVG iconed features not rendered correctly during zoom

Tags: geoserver

Im using Geoserver with PostGIS database to put points to map using GeoExplorer. The points are styled to use SVG icon with fixed size (uom metre, size) so they scale together with the map as user zooms in and out. For now, there are no filters or any other issues. Style code :

```
<sld:PointSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/metre">
        <sld:Graphic>
          <sld:ExternalGraphic>
            <sld:OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="load_icon.php?id=${param}"/>
            <sld:Format>image/svg+xml</sld:Format>
          </sld:ExternalGraphic>
          <sld:Size>80000</sld:Size>
        </sld:Graphic>
      </sld:PointSymbolizer>
      <sld:TextSymbolizer/>
```

load_icon.php is returning the SVG code for given param :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="220" height="110">
<g transform="scale(0.5)">
<g transform="translate(90,50)">                
<rect x="1.5" y="1.5" height="103" width="167" fill="#fff" stroke="red" stroke-width="3"/>
<path d="M3,3 l164,100 m0,-100 l-164,100" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="none"/>
</g>
<text x="173" y="49" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Verdana" font-size="25" fill="red">XXXXX< /text>
<text x="270" y="153" font-family="Verdana" font-size="25" fill="red">G< /text>
</g>
</svg>
```

I use the plain GeoExplorer to view the icon on the map, but same issue is when connecting the layer as WMS to Leaflet and other libraries.

The icon is showing ok in some resolution :
[image: icon ok]

but gets cropped as user is zooming in :
[image: icon croped]

and even more cropped with further zoom :
[image: icon more cropped]

with tiles that do not contain the part of the icon. There is caching turned off for this layer, no help.

What I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: so after some experimenting, the only solution working so far is to turn SINGLE TILE option on, then the SVG icons do render correctly, but as expected, the loading is bit slower and tends to be more user un-friendly :(

Comment: How about to convert SVG icons in PNG icons created for different scale ranges. This would imply different sld Rules, but it probably would improve the performance.

Comment: good idea, will give it a try ... another option I was thinking about was to show the layer via GeoJSON and style it on client side, but I didnt progres on that yet.

Comment: so I did try, and the result is very unsatisfying too :( some of the icons corrupted when loaded via SVG are fixed now, but there are some others which are still corrupted (especially on the border of the tiles)

Comment: I turned on cache, used Metatiling factors 10x10 tiles and 100px gutter, and now all the icons appear ok

Comment: Sorry, one more comment - when it works in geoExplorer, it does not work in Leafletjs :( this is so confusing, I have no idea why two identical sources do and do not work :(

Comment: Ok.For me this procedure has worked well apart from the annoying rules and scale intervals management.

Comment: I don't know "Leafletjs" but if the layer works fine in the geoserver preview I could think that the problem is not in the style files.

Comment: so far I've found one spot where are four icons, each of them truncated at some point, at one given zoom. It does in my test leaflet map (javascript library as openlayer, just way much smaller), but it does not in geoexplorer (another javascript library/webpage built on extjs). The zoom is the same, as far as I can see, the area is the same, and Im getting two different results :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens since the client JavaScript library requests (small) tiles from the GeoServer. I recommend you to use the integrated GeoWebCache as WMS endpoint. In the GeoWebCache settings you can define the metatile size (see *Caching Defaults* in *TileCaching* menu), this means GeoServer internally renders a large image and split it into tiles. So you won't have this effect of cut symbols anymore.

Finally change your WMS endpoint from `/geoserver/wms` to`/geoserver/gwc/service/wms`

Comment: Dear sir/ma'am, you are absolutly correct, now it works as expected ! Thank you !